# Firebase Energy Impact

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I run app on my phone (Iphone XS) the app's energy impact goes high-very high position. Especially while getting data from Firebase. My question is even my app is not even complex and I have not much pods in my project, is it ok to get this impact? Any experiences would be appreciated (Cpu under %20 all the time and thermal state is nominal).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could be useful if you describe how you are managing the data retrieved from your Firebase instance, also I suggest you take a look at this documenthttps://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't see any relevance with managing the data? If you read and look the question, you see it's about network and overhead component..